# Trying to catch warning on database when entering duplicate values in sql database php

Tags: php, postgresql

i am trying to catch this error in a php webapp that captures input data from a user. im using php and sql on mypgadmin, sourcecode column constraints :  "`CONSTRAINT sourcecodes_sourcecode_key UNIQUE (sourcecode)`"

**ERROR**

> Warning: pg_execute() [function.pg-execute]: Query failed: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "sourcecodes_sourcecode_key" DETAIL: Key (sourcecode)=(Source3) already exists. in D:\xampp\htdocs ...php on line 289

Problem when user enters an existing sourcecode then the error is generated on POSTING the value.

**Code**

```
if(array_key_exists("btnsubmit", $_POST)) {
    $pk_check = "true";


    if($pk_check == "true") {
        $parameters = array();
        $parameters[] = $counter;

        $parameters[] = $_POST['source'];


        $sql_string = "INSERT INTO config.sourcecodes (id,sourcecode ) VALUES ($1,$2 )";


        try {
            $saved = $db_cfg->Execute($sql_string, "", $parameters);


            if($saved) {
                $feedback = 'New Campaign: ' . $_POST['campaign_id'] . ' Saved  successfully';
            } else {
                error_reporting(32);
                $feedback = "_Error Saving Source Code ! _";
                //echo pg_last_notice($sql_string) ;
                //  throw new $exception('Error saving new source code');
            }
        }
        catch(\sdException $exception) {
            throw new Exception('fatal err trycatch nt wrkn');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your query adding a 'ON DUPLICATE KEY' to catch the error on a db level, check out : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Note:
You can fake the update by `...UPDATE c=c;` for example

Ex: '`INSERT INTO config.sourcecodes (id,sourcecode ) VALUES ($1,$2 ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = $1`'

PostgreSQL 9.5:

```
INSERT INTO config.sourcecodes (id,sourcecode ) VALUES ($1,$2 )
ON CONFLICT (sourcecode) DO UPDATE SET id = id;
```

Or by catching exceptions:

```
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO config.sourcecodes (id,sourcecode ) VALUES ($1,$2 );
EXCEPTION 
   WHEN unique_violation THEN
     UPDATE config.sourcecodes SET sourcecode = sourcecode WHERE id = $1;
END;
```

Comment: Why should he catch an exception that can be solved witought headaches?

Comment: it does not answer the OP's question

Comment: If his approach is not very good and an answer that has a different approach but solves the big picture is invalid?
Also your`s isn't as well :)

Comment: i get this error:
"Warning: pg_prepare() [function.pg-prepare]: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "ON" LINE 1 " when adding this "ON DUPLICATEKEY UPDATE   sourcecode = $3" to my insert